# The CSS style of contact form doesn't show in mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I created a contact form and customized it with some CSS. I also added a little animation.

The problem is that on mobile I don't see all the changes I've made.
For example, the input fields that I had removed the background from are no longer transparent.

CSS:

```
form {
    width: 60%;
   margin: auto;
}

form .input-data input{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0%;
    outline: none !important;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: silver;
  
}


.form-control:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    border-color: white;
}


form label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

form .input-data input:focus ~ label ,
form .input-data input:valid ~ label {
    transform: translateY(-25px);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: silver;
}
```

Comment: Have you try to refresh the cache of your mobile browser?

Comment: Share also the important part of your html. What browser are you using in mobile?

Comment: @alotropico I tried to put also the html code (only the form) but it wouldn't let me post the question because there was too much code. but know it works